# Allow the same project to be opened and built with Android Studio OR IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I develop an SDK, and would like to be able to check in module files for both IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio. I've devised the following solution, with one missing piece:

1. Create module files ending in -intellij-idea for the main project, and each module.
2. Create build.gradle files, and use the "sourceset" directive to use the old style src and res directory structure.

The problem is that the project information is always stored in a directory called ".idea". Before, I could have two IPR files, such as my-project-android-studio.ipr and my-project-intellij-idea.ipr. I could then open one in Android Studio, and the other in Intellij IDEA, but the actual source would remain the same.

How can I accomplish this? If there is a way to force Android Studio to generate IPR files instead of the ridiculous .idea directory, that would be optimal.